# In firebase chat how to update receiver user on chat message send in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am try to make firebase chat message sent but not update on the other user.
But the message update on the firebase data base.

my Code is :-

```
guard let myid = “Xyz”
database.child(ChatDataBase.messages).child("\(conversation)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { [weak self] snapshot in
    guard let strongSelf = self else {
    return
}
let messageDate = newMessage.sentDate
let dateString = ChatViewController.dateFormatters.string(from: messageDate)
var message = “text”
let newMessageEntry: [String: Any] = [
    "id": newMessage.messageId,
    ChatConstant.content: message,
    ChatConstant.sender_id: myid,
    ChatConstant.reciever_id: otherUserId,
]

guard let keys = self?.database.childByAutoId().key else {
    completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
    return
}

let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child(ChatDataBase.messages).child(conversation)
let userMessages = messageDB.queryOrdered(byChild: ChatConstant.reciever_id).queryEqual(toValue: otherUserId)
strongSelf.database.child(ChatDataBase.messages).child("\(conversation)").child(keys).setValue(newMessageEntry) { (error, ref) in
guard error == nil else {
    completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
    return
},userMessages.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    if let conversations_value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
    }

} withCancel:nil}
completion(.success(newMessageEntry))}

}}
```

Comment: you should share some code in order for us to help you out.

Comment: plz have a look this code and help to find me correct answer.